# Unresolved reference when using variable

Tags: python, function, variables

I'm trying to join a variable from a function in a list, but it says the variable is an unresolved reference. I've had a look around and can't find any explanations that I can understand as to why this might be. The error is on the variable IP from the function. Can anyone help and explain in simple terms please?

```
def get_ip():
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    try:
        # doesn't even have to be reachable
        s.connect(('10.255.255.255', 1))
        IP = s.getsockname()[0]
    except:
        IP = '127.0.0.1'
    finally:
        s.close()
    usersip = IP
    print(IP)
    return IP
get_ip()

list_to_join = [time, nameofhost, hostsname, message, clients_input, IP,] #Errors when I try to include the time_at_start variable
delimiter = '&&'
datajoined = delimiter.join(list_to_join)
```

Comment: Please post the entire stack trace so we can see the exact error and which line failed.

Comment: In the code, as it is, all of these are undefined variables: `time`, `nameofhost`, `hostsname`, `message`, `clients_input`, `IP`

Answer (score 1):

`IP` is a local variable inside of `get_ip()`. You can't use it outside of the function; it doesn't exist there.

Assign `get_ip()`'s return value to a variable and use that variable. You could name that variable `IP` as well. But to be clear, it's a different variable. Let's use a different name to make that obvious:

```
ip = get_ip()
list_to_join = [time, nameofhost, hostsname, message, clients_input, ip]
```